# Stored procedure for Inserting Data into 3 tables. Not working.

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables-

```
1. Country (CountryName, CID (PK- AutoIncrement))
2. State (SID(PK- AutoIncrement), StateName, CID (FK to Country)
3. City (CityName, CID, SID (FK to State)
```

Now I need to insert only the name into the three tables with CountryName, StateName and CityName.. The IDs need to get updated.

```
Create PROCEDURE sp_place(
    @CountryName char(50),
    @StateName  varchar(50),
    @CityName   nchar(20)
    )
AS
DECLARE @CountryID int, @StateID int, @CityID int;

Set NOCOUNT OFF

BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO dbo.Country VALUES (@CountryName);
SET @CountryID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

IF @@ERROR <> 0 
BEGIN     
ROLLBACK     
RETURN 
END 

Insert into dbo.State VALUES (@StateName, @CountryID);
SET @StateID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
IF @@ERROR <> 0 
BEGIN     
ROLLBACK     
RETURN 
END 

Insert into dbo.City VALUES (@CityName, @StateID);
SET @CityID= SCOPE_IDENTITY();

Commit
```

When I Enter Country twice, the value shouldn't get changed.
Eg: If I enter India the value of CountryID=1, when I again enter India, the value of CountryID shouldn't get increased.

How'd I perform that? My SP changes for every insertion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the country already exist and retrieve the countryID

```
IF NOT EXISTS(Select 1 FROM Country Where CountryName=@Country)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Country VALUES (@CountryName);
    SET @CountryID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
ELSE
    Select @CountryID = CountryID From Country Where CountryName=@Country
```

You can do the same for `State` and `City` if required

Comment: I understood your codes.. But I used in my SP but getting error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'THEN'" Any which ways the problem is **one Country** can have more than one state. With your code, I'm unable to add more States and Cities.

Comment: Immediately after that I used INSERT INTO dbo.State, and giving an error, telling "Expecting CONVERSATION"..

Comment: Thanks mate :) Was off a great help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Hello try with this syntax

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Country WHERE CountryName= @CountryName)
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.Country
    SET CountryName = @CountryName
    WHERE   CountryId = (SELECT CountryId FROM dbo.Country WHERE CountryName= @CountryName);
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO dbo.Country(CountryName) VALUES (@CountryName);

END

-- For the identity you must just add identity to your column in your creation script
```

Comment: I used your code. But the problem is one Country can have more than one state. With your code, I'm unable to add more States and Cities.

Comment: it's not problem, because CID is foreign key in your state table  or cities table

Comment: CID is FK in state table and SID is FK in City table. That is what my concern is... Each Country has more than one states.. In this code, I cannot Execute multiple States.

Comment: this code is just for add contry entities, you must to adjust code for add states and cities

Comment: with your contry label , you find your CID, and insert your CID n yours cities and states tables

Answer (score 0):

You need the `MERGE` syntax

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

or to check manually (ie: with `IF EXISTS (...)` ) for the existence of the country before inserting.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you set [Unique Constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp) on CountryName column that won't allow you to insert  duplicate countries at all